# How is "cin>>" different from "cin.get"? OR Is it not?

Tags: c++, output, cin

I was coding a program for Multiplication Tables... And I used `a=cin.get();` and `cin>>a;` to input the value. I got different results with each. The code is:

```
#include"pch.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

float a, b;

cout << "Enter the number:";
a = cin.get();
cout << "The Table for the given number is:" << endl;
for (b = 1; b <= 10; ++b)
{
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << a * b << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

And the other one is:

```
#include"pch.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()

{  

float a, b;

cout << "Enter the number:";
cin >> a;
cout << "The Table for the given number is:" << endl;
for (b = 1; b <= 10; ++b)
{
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << a * b << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

The one with `cin>>a;` worked fine. 
I once read that `cin.get()` is also used to get the value of the variable. Does it have some other use instead of this?

Thanks,

Comment: `cin.get();` can't read a `float`, it deals in single characters, and `cin >> a;` can.

Comment: [Documentation for `std::istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

Comment: This is a valid - and well composited - question according to the fact that **```>>``` is part of ```<istream>```** - and can be considered as a method (*```operator>>()```*) - **just like ```get()```**. So, give it some credit and upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many newbies you're a bit confused about *types*. `cin >> a` will read from `cin` into variable `a` no matter what type `a` is, so `float`, `int`, `std::string` etc all work with `>>`. That's a simplification but close enough for now.

`a = cin.get()` is for reading single characters only, it returns the next character in the input. What's happening in your first program is that a char value from `get()` is being converted to a float value. Skipping over the details but that's not something that makes a lot of sense, which is why you get the strange results.

Another difference between `>>` and `get()` is that `>>` will skip whitespace but `get()` will not. So if you want to read a single character irrespective of whether it's whitespace or not then use `get()` otherwise use `>>`.

Comment: Yes, I am new. Thanks. But can you explain a bit slow? I mean it went over my head(the cin.get() part). What kind of a single character?

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: About a=cin.get();  can you give an example?

Comment: Say the input is four characters, you type abc then enter. Then the first time you call `cin.get()` it will return 'a', then second time 'b' the third time 'c' the fourth time '\n'. It just reads one character at a time.

Comment: OK. So in my my program, when it type 'a=cin.get();' , it will return the first value I enter? like 2 or an digit?

Comment: Yes, but it will then convert that character to a float, which is where things get confusing, and I skipped over that part in my explanation. For instance if you enter 2 then that would get converted to a float value of 50. I said it was confusing.If you want to understand why then you should look up in a good book how characters are represented in a C++ program

Comment: Now it starts making sense. Thanks a lot. I should start reading.  I think I know that. Maybe it is because of the ASCII. Am I right? like a-z will be from specific numbers and A-Z will from some other set of numbers...

Comment: Yep, ASCII is the key (though strictly C++ doesn't require use of ASCII, but you're very unlikely to see anything else).

Answer (score 2):

### In summary:

The `>>` operator is the *Binary Right Shift Operator*. This has been overloaded - in the `<istream>` class - to have a different - and very complex - functionality. I would say: to become a high level "method".

`get()` is a simpler method of `<istream>` which cannot handle data types (floats, etc.).

### In detail:

Internally, the `>>` operator uses similar logic to `get()`/`getline()`, but then it applies the magic: **it *parses* the input value into the required data type** (float, in your case).

And they did not stop at parsing, this operator has a complex logic to handle formatting and other requests. Example:

```
cin >> hex >> a    //you can input "0x3f9d70a4" to get 1.23
```

Check [the description of "*operator>>*"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) for further info.